# Variable Not Defined Error Enigma

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to automate PowerPoint from Excel. Everything worked fine. I have the following code block that worked perfectly:

```
Set MyTextbox = mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, Left:=myShape.Left - 3, Top:=42, Width:=myShape.Width + 6, Height:=10).TextFrame.TextRange
With MyTextbox
    .Text = Format(MyShapeDate, "m/yy")
    .Font.Size = 11
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

I saved the code as an addin and tried to add a new tab and a button, unsuccessfully. So I brought the code back to the workbook. When I tried to run it again I get a variable not defined for `ppAlignCenter`. Would anyone know why this is happening or if it is a common error?

Comment: `ppAlignCenter` sounds like a PowerPoint constant.  Have you still got all the necessary references included?

Comment: It is a PowerPoint constant and I am using late binding. But it worked perfectly numerous times.

Comment: if you are using late binding, `ppAlignCenter` is meaningless unless you give it a value.

Comment: Are you sure that, despite using late binding, you didn't also previously have a reference to the PowerPoint library?

Comment: @vacip Yes, I understand now. I got it working making the alignment equal to 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *It is a PowerPoint constant and I am using late binding. But it worked perfectly numerous times.*

Then you were **NOT** late-binding.

Put yourself in VBA's shoes: you're compiling that project, and you come across `ppAlignCenter` as a token/identifier. If `Option Explicit` is turned on (it *should*!), and the PowerPoint object library isn't referenced, then `ppAlignCenter` is an undeclared variable, and you don't know what to do with it - so you throw your hands in the air and scream at the user:

> Compile error: variable not defined.

If `Option Explicit` is not turned on, and PowerPoint isn't referenced, then you "declare" an uninitialized `Variant` variable on-the-spot, named `ppAlignCenter`, so that the assignment of `MyTextBox.ParagraphFormat.Alignment` can be compiled.

Because the variable isn't initialized, at runtime its value will just be `0` - and from there it's not clear what happens, because [PpParagraphAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745375.aspx) has no member with a value of `0`, so it's possible that the `MyTextBox.ParagraphFormat.Alignment` assignment raises a runtime error as well, but that's entirely up to the `Alignment` property's implementation.

Now, if the PowerPoint library *is* referenced (early-bound), then `ppAlignCenter` resolves to that `PpParagraphAlignment.ppAlignCenter` enum value which you know is really just a `2`, and so you can proceed to compile.

---

The `PpParagraphAlignment` enum is defined in the PowerPoint type library, so if you are late-binding to that library, you can't refer to its members by name, because VBA will try to resolve them at compile-time - and fail to do so.

So instead of this:

```
.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
```

You need to do this:

```
.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2 'ppAlignCenter
```

---

But why would you late-bind to a type library you *know* you need to have anyway for the program to even *hope* to work at runtime?

Late-binding means you're working with `Object` variables instead of specific types - and that means runtime interface lookups and quite a bit of overhead *that you don't need at all*... and these lookups are going to fail anyway if the library isn't present. Not to mention, programming against `Object` means you don't get *IntelliSense* and need to quadruple-check everything you're doing, because the compiler isn't going to help you and the runtime will scream if you make a typo.

...that said, early-bound references are version-specific - so if you're distributing your code to users running different versions of the libraries you're referencing, late-binding will ensure everything works for everyone (provided your code isn't using API features that are version-specific). In that case the best compromise is to *develop* with early-bound references (so you get *IntelliSense* and autocompletion!), and then switch everything over to late-bound when you distribute it.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Constantly learning. Makes total sense and resolved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: RE last paragraph: if you're using the macro in an environment where all users are running different versions of PowerPoint, distributing a late-bound version of the macro will ensure everything works for everyone; an early-bound reference is version-specific.

Comment: Great explanation, @Mat'sMug ... I'm upvoting it too, but it'd be useful if you'd edit the answer to include the info about late-binding in your comment re version-specificity.  Thx!

Comment: @Mat'sMug And even improved, no less.  Thanks!